# Show that a subset $A$ is open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

$A:=\{x\in \Bbb R : \sin(x) + x \cos^2(x)\lt \frac 12 \}$

If $A$ is a subset of $\Bbb R$ then show that it's open.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you written down the definition of an open set, and checked if the above set satisfies the definition?

Comment: I think you should prove that using the definition of open set and the continuity of this function

Comment: Is $f(x)=\sin x+x\cos^2 x$ continuous? Is $(-\infty,1/2)$ open?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$f:x\mapsto \sin (x)+x\cos^2 (x) $$

$f $ is continuous at $\mathbb R $

$$\implies $$

$A=f^{-1}((-\infty,\frac {1}{2})) $ is an open of $\mathbb R $ as a preimage of the open $(-\infty,1/2) $ by a continuous function.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x_0 \in A$ (i.e. $f(x)<1/2)$, for continuity

$$\exists \delta>0: |x_0-x|<\delta \implies|f(x_0)-f(x)|<\frac{\frac{1}{2}-f(x_0)}{2} $$

note that the set {$x: |f(x_0)-f(x)|<\frac{\frac{1}{2}-f(x_0)}{2} $} is open, for continuity the preimage of this set is a open set which contains $x_0 \implies A$ open.